# Is this a viable strategy for avoiding the pro-rata rule for backdoor Roth while maintaining the superior investment options in my non-Roth IRA?

Tags: 401k, ira, rollover

Assume that my 401(k) supports both reverse rollover from IRA and in-service rollover to an IRA. I am doing a backdoor Roth, and want to avoid the pro-rata rule. The general way to do this is to reverse rollover the pre-tax IRA contributions to the 401(k) so that the pre-tax IRA balance is $0 on December 31. All good. However, my IRA investment options are significantly superior to my 401(k) plan, so I'd rather have the money in the IRA long term. Is it a (legal) viable strategy to reverse rollover the IRA to 401(k) late December so the balance is $0 on the 31st, and then in-service rollover the 401(k) back to the IRA on Jan 1, or is there some gotcha that I didn't find here?

Comment: `in-plan rollover the 401(k) back to the IRA` - it's either "in plan" or "back to the IRA", it cannot be both.

Comment: @littleadv I was given to understand that an `in-plan rollover` is a rollover to an IRA while the 401(k) is still active (as in, still working for the associated employer and making contributions to the 401(k)). Is that wrong?

Comment: that would be "in-service rollover"... In-plan usually refers to conversion from traditional (after-tax, usually) 401k into Roth 401k, something commonly refered to as "mega-backdoor".

Comment: Ahh, yup, I used the wrong word. Fixing it now.

Comment: For in-service distributions you need to read the plan terms carefully. They may not allow it to everyone, or from every source. Usually those who allow that, only allow for people beyond the age of 59.5, and in some cases I've seen distributions allowed for everyone, but only from after-tax sources (to facilitate mega backdoor into Roth IRA). So read your plan documents very carefully.

Comment: I'm surprised your 401(k) allows in-service rollovers and yet has poor enough investment choices to make this effort worthwhile.

Comment: @CraigW it's more diversification and alignment of interests than it is performance. My 401(k) assets are all in an S&P 500 index fund, and there's nothing to complain about that performance-wise. I have no good bond index fund or international index fund options, though.